# Attempt to connect to ExpressVPN Server fails

Tags: opensuse, openvpn, ssl

for several months, if not weeks, I have had a fully functional connection to an ExpressVPN server via the "NetworkManager" on OpenSuse, but now, suddenly, it reports "failed to activate" on every attempt to connect to any VPN server - I added multiple VPN servers to ensure that the problem is on my machine.

Here is what `sudo journalctl -fu NetworkManager` prints - since I am not sure which information I can leave and which not, I will redact some of them, which probably should be made public:

```
NetworkManager[12792]: <info>  [1685282870.1677] vpn[redacted,redacted,"New vpn connection"]: starting openvpn
NetworkManager[12792]: <info>  [1685282870.1681] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="redacted" name="New vpn connection" pid=14141 uid=1000 result="success"
nm-openvpn[3441]: Note: --cipher is not set. OpenVPN versions before 2.5 defaulted to BF-CBC as fallback when cipher negotiation failed in this case. If you need this fallback please add '--data-ciphers-fallback BF-CBC' to your configuration and/or add BF-CBC to --data-ciphers.
nm-openvpn[3441]: OpenVPN 2.6.4 x86_64-suse-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD]
nm-openvpn[3441]: library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023, LZO 2.10
nm-openvpn[3441]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
nm-openvpn[3441]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
nm-openvpn[3441]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]45.132.226.118:1195
nm-openvpn[3441]: UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
nm-openvpn[3441]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]45.132.226.118:1195
nm-openvpn[3441]: NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
NetworkManager[12792]: <warn>  [1685282930.2749] vpn[redacted,redacted,"New vpn connection"]: connect timeout exceeded
nm-openvpn-serv[3435]: Connect timer expired, disconnecting.
nm-openvpn[3441]: SIGTERM received, sending exit notification to peer
nm-openvpn[3441]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
nm-openvpn[3441]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
nm-openvpn[3441]: Converting soft SIGUSR1 received during exit notification to SIGTERM
nm-openvpn[3441]: SIGTERM[soft,exit-with-notification] received, process exiting
```

I already tried to enable the "TLS-Auth" and "TLS-Crypt" options, and of course, I provided the *-tls-auth.pem file. But I nevertheless get the same message.

The set-up of the VPN connection was tried in two ways:

- Automatically via the *.ovpn file
  This resulted in the following output

  ```
    NetworkManager[12792]: <info>  [1685280959.0985] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="redacted" name="MY_VPN" pid=14141 uid=1000 result="success"
    NetworkManager[31100]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [CMD-LINE]:1: keysize (2.6.4)
    NetworkManager[31100]: Use --help for more information.
    NetworkManager[12792]: <warn>  [1685280959.1498] vpn[redacted,redacted,"MY_VPN"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
    NetworkManager[12792]: <warn>  [1685280959.1498] vpn[redacted,redacted,"MY_VPN"]: dbus: failure: connect-failed (1)
  ```

  This seems to have changed due to an update of OpenVPN to version 2.4.
- Manually by extracting all the fields from the *.ovpn file, which resulted in the output I mentioned at the beginning.

And yes, I asked ChatGPT 4, which was not helpful either, so I guess real intelligence is needed instead of AI.

Comment: *"Connect timer expired"* - sounds to me like a plain connectivity problem, i.e. nothing about authentication. Check if the peer is up in the first place, awaiting data, no firewall in between your client and the server (or on the server) blocking the packets ... . Do a packet capture (for example using tcpdump) at the server to verify that the VPN packets get received and that response packets get sent back.

Comment: Sorry, for my late answer, I got sick. You are right, I don't get any packets back upon requests, but a normal ping works like a charm. How could I address this issue? I extracted the IP from the OVPN file freshly downloaded from ExpressVPN itself.

Comment: ping uses a different mechanism than the VPN. A firewall (at the server, but also somewhere else) might block the VPN traffic but let the ping pass. If this is a firewall at the server then a packet capture will show you the incoming packets (since these are captured before the firewall) but the VPN server will not get the packets and thus will not send a response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I still could not solve it, but I will figure something out eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to work around this issue by using the OpenVPN tool itself, rather than the built-in feature of the Network Manager, to connect to the VPN.

Still, to achieve this one needs to modify the OVPN file by removing the line that defines the `keysize` option, which is, as it seems, not supported anymore as of version 2.6 ([documentation](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/)).

Edit:
To clarify, it had nothing to do with the firewall or any other connectivity issue. The problem, as it seems, was the Network Manager of OpenSuse.